# compile Alsa drivers on modern Linux?

Tags: linux, audio, drivers, debian

i've been searching for the answer to this question for a long time. i'm using a combo-jack Realtek sound card (Realtek ALC283), and it's not really supported by default by the vast majority of OSes. output is just fine, however input doesn't work aside from the built-in microphone and USB devices. i managed to find the drivers, however i've been greeted with this:

[log file](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/636253207156228146/723513312884686909/Alsa-log.log)

i ran the make command as root, as it said in the instruction, however it still failed in the end. could it be the fact that my kernel is newer than the one listed in the recommended version? i failed to find a more modern driver for the card, despite a bit of research, therefore i'm stuck with this. any ideas how to get around it? it starts off fine and then, all of a sudden, returns a ton of errors. any help would be appreciated, thanks

btw, i uploaded it to Discord since this is the only link that won't expire

EDIT: i managed to find a way to override this, nevermind

Answer (score 0):

Linux does not have a stable driver interface. This is on purpose. The intention is that the drivers should be submitted into the mainline kernel, and kept up-to-date. If for some reason your driver has not been mainlined yet, you'll have to run an old kernel or update it your self.

For more details: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/process/stable-api-nonsense.rst